# using one element from one datafram to find all the information in the other datafram? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have 2 dataframe in python by running 2 sql queries.
Table A:

| Name | Email | Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | E | E1,E2,E3 |
| B | F | F1,F2 |
| C | G | G1 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Table B:

| Info1 | Code | Info2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | E1 | ... |
| ... | F1 | ... |
| ... | E2 | ... |
| ... | E3 | ... |
| ... | G1 | ... |
| ... | F2 | ... |

Because they are dataframe in Python, I would like to read the email one by one, and find its Code list/Array in TableA.
And use every elements in the list/array to find all the data in Table B, create excels and send to information's host.
For example,
I would to get the result excel like below and send it to E.

| Info1 | Code | Info2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | E1 | ... |
| ... | E2 | ... |
| ... | E3 | ... |

For example,
I would to get the result excel like below and send it to F.

| Info1 | Code | Info2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | F1 | ... |
| ... | F2 | ... |

For example,
I would to get the result excel like below and send it to G.

| Info1 | Code | Info2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | G1 | ... |

Please use dataframe in Python.
THANK YOU SO MUCH

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```py
new_df = df1.assign(Code=df['Code'].str.split(',')).explode('Code').merge(df2)
for email, sub_df in new_df.groupby(['Email']):
    print(f'Sending df to {email}...')
    print(sub_df.to_csv())
```

Output:

```
Sending df to E...
,Name,Email,Code,Info1,Info2
0,A,E,E1,...,...
1,A,E,E2,...,...
2,A,E,E3,...,...

Sending df to F...
,Name,Email,Code,Info1,Info2
3,B,F,F1,...,...
4,B,F,F2,...,...

Sending df to G...
,Name,Email,Code,Info1,Info2
5,C,G,G1,...,...
```